# (yaourt)ERROR: Cannot find the strip binary required for object file stripping

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, archlinux

I was attempting to install imwheel, a mouse configuration client for linux, and being a total noob was stumped when I came across this output upon attempting to install the package, as I had done so before and never had this issue (I used to use pacaur);

```
eman@alexandria ~                                                                                                                       
[17:38:40] 
> $ yaourt imwheel                                                                                                                                                                                                             

1 aur/imwheel 1.0.0pre12-5 (15) (1.41)
Mouse wheel configuration tool for XFree86/Xorg
==> Enter n° of packages to be installed (e.g., 1 2 3 or 1-3)
==> ---------------------------------------------------------
==> 1


==> Downloading imwheel PKGBUILD from AUR...
x .SRCINFO
x PKGBUILD
x etcdir-install.patch
Zeph commented on 2017-12-05 20:38           

imwheel 1.0.0pre12-5  (2015-08-14 12:11)
( Unsupported package: Potentially dangerous ! )
==> Edit PKGBUILD ? [Y/n] ("A" to abort)
==> ------------------------------------
==> y

==> imwheel dependencies:
 - libxtst (already installed)
 - libxmu (already installed)


==> Edit PKGBUILD ? [Y/n] ("A" to abort)
==> ------------------------------------
==> n

==> Continue building imwheel ? [Y/n]
==> ---------------------------------
==> y

==> Building and installing package
==> ERROR: pkgver is not allowed to contain colons, hyphens or 
whitespace.

==> ERROR: An unknown error has occurred. Exiting...
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build imwheel.
```

Upon seeing this, I spent a good hour looking for errors in both the package build file and the comments of the build itself to see if there was a simple fix. Unfortunately, like I have done many times, I was approaching the issue completely incorrectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately, neither did the solution require the editing of config files (which pains me deeply), nor did it require manual building (which also pains me). Instead, this was a two part problem.

**First**, the issue of the package not being supported, after doing some homework on it, turned out to simply boil down to a general warning (not even an error!) regarding the fact that AUR(Arch User Repository) packages are publicly produced, and therefore have the potential to be malicious. Of course we know imwheel does not fall into this category, so we may brush this first warning off unfazed, although I recommend to always vet your packages before making and/or installing them due to their very real malicious potential. **So to recap the first problem (the warning about the package not being supported), there is no reason with the given package to fear it, therein rendering this error/warning no longer an obstacle to this installation**.

**Second,** We have the daunting `ERROR: pkgver is not allowed to contain colons, hyphens or whitespace.` Anyone in the right mind would turn to editing an alleged syntactical error in the package buildfile, although this is also a deceiving error. Although this time around, the error is a brick wall in our installation, and not a mere mirage of a warning, it also leads us to a quite elegant (and by that I mean simple) solution. As it turns out, Arch with the latest Anarchy installer does not ship with all of the build tools you might have found in prior fresh installs with Arch-anywhere. Alas, all we need to do is install the packages `core/make` `core/patch` `core/gcc` `core/autoconf` `core/automake` `core/binutils` `core/bison` and `core/fakeroot` , which are all under the `core` repository, and all of which fall under the tag `base-devel`. 
**In recap, all we needed were the following unmet prerequisite packages: `core/make` `core/patch` `core/gcc` `core/autoconf` `core/automake` `core/binutils` `core/bison` and `core/fakeroot` , which are all under the `core` repository, and all of which fall under the tag `base-devel`.**

I hope I was of help for those like-minded linux noobs, and I wish all those who can apply this knowledge some happy hacking!

Comment: You rock! I was having almost the exactly problem, but the solution was the same tho. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!